# Q:span automaticlly changes its shape when it animates to the border of its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey I'm currently building a bullet-comment pen on codepen,everything works fine but there's one problem.
The "bullet" span that contains a text with space in it automaticaly changes its shape when it reaches #screen's left border .
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGCP6.jpg
I don't know how to fix this problem.
This is my codepen https://codepen.io/NuclearBlast/pen/zzOQEO 
HTML:

```
.container
.row#row1
div.col-md-10#screen
.row#row2
div#control.col-md-10.col-md-offset-1
  input(type="text" placeholder="Say something" )#input
  div#buttons
    button.btn.btn-default#btnshoot(type="button"  disabled) shoot
    button.btn.btn-default#btnclear clear
```

JS:

```
$("#btnshoot").click(function shootBullet(){
  var cmt=$("#input").val();
  var screen=document.getElementById("screen");
  var bullet = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var textNode=document.createTextNode(cmt);
  bullet.appendChild(textNode);
  $(bullet).css({"max-
height":"30px","right":"-50px","bottom":rdmHeight()+"","width":"auto","font-
size":"2em","position":"absolute"});
 console.log($(bullet).css("bottom"));
 screen.appendChild(bullet); 

$(bullet).animate(
{right:$(screen).width()+$(this).width()},5000,"linear",function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
 $("#input").val("");
  //generate a random css bottom value for the bullet
  function rdmHeight(){
    var scrH=$(screen).height();
    var rdmH=Math.random()*scrH;
    if(rdmH+50>scrH){
       rdmH=scrH-30;
           }
     return rdmH+"px";
      }
```

Comment: bullet -> white-space: nowrap;

Comment: @WilliamValhakis Hah! I see you edited your comment.

Comment: what do you mean ? You mean I changed it to his answer ? :D Hover over the time, I answered 7 seconds before him. :D

Comment: @WilliamValhakis actually it's 7 seconds after him nvm I was just kidding,thanks to you too!

Comment: No, you don't understand. After he answered, the global timezone time was shifted 14 seconds backwards.

Comment: @WilliamValhakis Oh I didn't know this! Thanks for delivering this unknown fact!

Comment: I did not know either, but the voices in my head told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the text wrapping to the next line when it hits the side, you can use the CSS `white-space` property:

```
span {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```